# juju can't deploy from charmstore, can't read entity archive

Tags: juju

I'm trying to deploy some charms from the charm store that has always been working. Wether I'm deploying with the GUI or cli, I get the same error:

> Could not add requested charm. Server responded with: cannot read
>   entity archive: write
>   /var/lib/juju/charmcache/charm-download924725467: no space left on
>   device

Trying in another model, gives me no errors.

Comment: 1) Can you share with us what are you trying to deploy and 2) where (i.e. Cloud, lolcal machine, 3) what is the output of "df -h" on machine that you are trying to deploy, 4) version of juju or dpkg - l | grep juju, 5) OS that you are using, 6) what is juju bootstrapped to.

Comment: 1) `juju deploy mongodb` 2 and 6) GCE  on JAAS 3) I'm not deploying to a specific machine 4) 2.3.8-bionic-amd64 5) Ubuntu 18.04